# Простая форма, которая будет запускатся на macOs при помощи VS 2017 и C#

Tags: c#, form, macos

нужна мультиплатформенная форма с одним компонетном на ней, которую возможно запустить под линуксом, макос и виндою.

Как сделать? В .Net Core я вижу исключительно консольные аплихуки. Гугление посылает в Xamarin Studio, который уже, вроде как, скачать нельзя ибо заменен самой VS 2017. =(

Comment: ну это наверное от компонента зависит. Mono смотрели?

Comment: компонент так же должен быть мультиплатформенным -- собственно это Chromium браузер. :)

Comment: Чисто в теории это можно сделать напрямую в VS 2017. В Xamarin Studio эта возможность была из коробки.... Не могли же ее просто снести когда вшивали в VS.

Comment: Я, как и вы, работал  только с Xamarin Studio, а как она выглядит в VS понятия не имею. Но если вам нужна только форма, а внутри браузер, может вам подойдет что то типа [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)? Я его не использовал, но он вроде кроссплатформенный и использует chromium внутри

Comment: Возможно и подойдет. Вся проблема в том, что в идеале у меня должна быть консольная программа, которая может вызывать такую форму. Пока что у Электрона я нахожу туторы как его использовать для веб-проэктов, но не вижу как использовать тем способом, которым мне нужно... На том же винформс я это делаю в пару кликов) А там -- хрен его знает возможно ли... Мне бы в идеале просто хромиум + кросплатформенную форму пустую...

Comment: ну, я насколько знаю, эти новомодные редакторы vscode, atom, brackets - написаны с помощью электрона, и вполне себе запускаются с консоли

Comment: покопаю, спасибо.

Comment: Гуглите GtkSharp, Eto.Forms, AvaloniaUi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net core официально не имел и не имеет поддержки форм и визуального программирования. Но уже много лет существует проект mono. Несмотря на то, что microsoft выкупила его и интегрировала xamarin (мобильная часть) в студию, mono остается отдельной веткой, предназначенной для кроссплатформенной десктопной разработки с графическим интерфейсом, в том числе и под macos. А Xamarin никогда не поддерживал macos, он создан для мобильной разработки (под ios, android). Так что в его сторону можно даже не смотреть,вам нужен mono

Разработка под mono ведётся в среде mono develop. Это открытая ide, исходники которой доступны на Github. В ней неофициально есть поддержка winforms, основной интерфейс - gtk+. Раньше поднималась идея разработка под mono на vs,  и были выпущены специальные модули разработки mono 2.6-3.0 - аналог net framework 4.0 и 3.2 как аналог mono для .net 4.5, на которые можно заменить целевую платформу проекта, но потом энтузиазм потух. Насколько мне известно, под более поздние версии таких модулей под vs нет. Но указанные мной версии можно поискать в сети. 
Так же есть проект avalonia, который должен стать кроссплатформенным аналогом wpf. Можете поискать в nuget

Comment: >> А Xamarin никогда не поддерживал macos

Если это так, то тогда как может существовать вот это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5mzgzvxcX8 - пример создания формы для макОС на ксамарине :)

Comment: @Andrew, с мобильного ссылка не открывается. Но немного погуглив, обнаружил, что действительно существует xamarin.mac https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac. Судя по описанию очень схож с разработкой на xamarin под ios. Но это всё-таки думаю не то, что вам нужно, если вы хотите, чтобы этот же код работал под Винду и Линукс. Советую, присмотреться к mono